# Multiple inheritance issue with templates and interfaces

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am working on a project that uses a tcl interpreter,  we bind c++ objects and methods to tcl commands. The bindings are c++ functions that have a ClientData pointer parameter (which is pretty much a void*).  We then cast this as the object we are expecting it to be, and interact with the object.

I am working on incorporating a set of classes that are templated. When I bind these classes to tcl commands, I do not know the template parameters, so I am using abstract 'interface' base classes to interact with them and putting the template parameter in an implementation class, so I don't need the template parameter to use them.

On top of that, I have a base class that handles all the common operations, and derived classes to do everything else, both have interface classes.

I created a simple example to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish. But my code is obviously more complex.

**StackTest.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#define STRLEN 1000
class BaseInterFace
{
public:
    BaseInterFace(){};
    virtual ~BaseInterFace(){};
    virtual const char *GetNameOfClass() const=0;
    virtual void BaseAction()=0;
};

template<typename T>
class Base: public BaseInterFace
{
public:
    Base(){};
    virtual ~Base(){};
    virtual const char *GetNameOfClass() const
    {
        std::cout << "This is " << this << std::endl;
        return "Base";
    }

    virtual void BaseAction(){
        printf("Base Action Done.\n");
    }
};
class DerivedInterface
{
public:
    DerivedInterface(){};
    virtual ~DerivedInterface(){};
    virtual void DerivedAction(double value)=0;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived :
public Base<T>,public DerivedInterface
{

public:
    char tclName_[STRLEN];
    Derived(){};
    virtual ~Derived(){};
    virtual const char *GetNameOfClass() const
    {   std::cout << "This is " << this << std::endl;
        return "Derived";
    }
    virtual void DerivedAction(double value){
        printf("Derived Action Done.\n");
    }

};
```

**Simple Example**
This example doesn't make sense since I know the type. But it simulates when I don't which is how I am using this.

```
Derived <short> *a = new Derived <short>();
void *cd = (void *)a;
printf("Base_BaseActionMtd\n");
BaseInterFace *b = (BaseInterFace *)cd;
printf("InputClass: %s\n",b->GetNameOfClass());
b->BaseAction();
printf("Done!\n");
BaseInterFace *b2 = (BaseInterFace *)cd;
printf("InputClass: %s\n",b2->GetNameOfClass());
DerivedInterface *c = (DerivedInterface *)cd;
c->DerivedAction(.01);
printf("Done!\n");
```

**This outputs:**

```
Base_BaseActionMtd
This is 0x1089fdc00
InputClass: Derived
Base Action Done.
Done!
This is 0x1089fdc00
InputClass: Derived
This is 0x1089fdc00
Done!
```

The derived action isn't taking place, and its calling GetNameOfClass?  I don't understand.  Even if I put a printf in the derivedinterface, that doesn't show up.
Also, if I switch the inheritance order in derived I get strange behavior from BaseAction.
It looks like I have something strange happening with the vtables. Could this have something to do with the template parameter?
If I cast using `(Derived<short> *)` it works fine.
I would like to understand what I am doing wrong, and how to properly do MI in general, and with templates.

As far as I can tell there isn't any ambiguity with the operations. 
So my question is two-fold.
1) Is MI the right answer here? There are many many classes that will need to be derived, and another inheritance chain that will use the same Base, so I would like to reuse as much code as possible. But I would rather avoid MI if there is a better way.
2) What am I doing wrong with MI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, there are far too many syntax errors in this code to take it at face value (`template<T>`, `virtual DerivedAction()=0;` `Derived<short> a = new Derived<short>();` etc etc etc).

Comment: This is too verbose and not a minimum working example. You should produce a minimum working example and reduce the text to state the problem you are having and where you are having it. I don't think you will be penalized for it; but I do think people are going to avoid it because its a lot of work to try and parse it. I know I stopped reading after the first paragraph.

Comment: Edited it.  Sorry, I copy pasted the wrong h file.  I put it into one file and removed the tcl code.  This behavior occurs with my simple example as well.

Comment: Why on earth are you casting to `BaseInterFace`? It isn't part of the inheritance chain, this is simply undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line is, if you know what a void* will be cast *to*, then cast *from* that same pointer type when casting to void*.  Anything else has the potential to fail in a multi-inheritance scenario.  In your case, replace this:

```
Derived<short> *d = new Derived<short>();
void *cd = (void*)d;
DerivedInterface *di = (DerivedInterface*)cd;
di->DerivedAction(.01);
```

with this:

```
Derived<short> *d = new Derived<short>();
DerivedInterface *di = (DerivedInterface*)d;
void *cd = (void*)di;
DerivedInterface *di2 = (DerivedInterface*)cd;
di2->DerivedAction(.01);
```

What makes the first code wrong and the second code right is that the second code uses the same pointer type in both casts to/from void*.

Let's take a look at object layout to understand why this is the case, and why your example ends up calling the wrong function.  (Note: this discussion is conceptually correct, but implementations don't match this exactly.  It's close enough to show you how to code correctly.)

First, let's look at the layout for a BaseInterface object:

[image: layout of BaseInterface object]

As you know, you can't actually instantiate a BaseInterface object because of the pure virtual methods, but when working with a BaseInterface pointer, this is the layout the compiler expects.  There is a compiler-generated member variable, vtable, that points to an array of function pointers, one per virtual function.  A call to `base_interface_instance->GetNameOfClass()` is actually a call to `base_interface_instance->vtable[1]()`, and `base_interface_instance->BaseAction()` is actually a call to `base_interface_instance->vtable[2]()`.

The layout for a Base object looks just like the layout for a BaseInterface.  When you create an object of this type, the vtable holds pointers to the Base class's implementations of each virtual function.  A call to `base_instance->GetNameOfClass()` looks just like it did with the BaseInterface object, `base_instance->vtable[1]`.

If Base had any additional virtual functions beyond what is defined in BaseInterface, they would have just been placed at the end of the vtable.  That's why, with single inheritance, you can do a simple cast up and down the inheritance chain and safely use the resulting pointer (as long as the object really is of the type you are casting to, or derived from it).  They all use the same vtable pointer to call virtual functions.  The more derived classes just happen to know that the vtable extends further down, giving access to virtual functions which were defined later in the inheritance chain.

The DerivedInterface layout looks like this:

[image: DerivedInterface layout]

Multiple inheritance is a little different.  An instance of your Derived class looks like this:

[image: Derived class layout]

Now it should be clear why the wrong function was getting called.  After casting from a void* to a DerivedInterface*, the compiler thinks it is working with the memory layout of a DerivedInterface object, but it's actually pointing at the portion of the object that reflects the BaseInterface layout.  `c->DerivedAction()` is calling `c->vtable[1]`, but vtable is pointing at BaseInterface's virtual methods (vtable1 in the Derived class layout), not DerivedInterface's methods (vtable2 in the Derived class layout).  `vtable[1]` is `Base::GetNameOfClass()`, not `Derived::DerivedAction()`.

So, to repeat the bottom line, if you know what a void* will be cast *to*, then cast *from* that same pointer type when casting to void*.  Anything else has the potential to fail in a multi-inheritance scenario.

Comment: In your example you added a template parameter to `DerivedInterface<short>`  Was this intended?  I won't know the template parameter. Your explanation is what I was looking for.  I knew something with the vtables was going wrong, but I wanted more specifics, thank you. Also, If I made DerivedInterface inherit from BaseInterface how would that effect this?

Comment: i.e. Diamond inheritance.

Comment: No, that was a mistake.  The template stuff really doesn't affect the issue you are running into.

Comment: No worries. Thats what I figured.  If I do diamond inheritance (DerivedInterface now inherits from BaseInterface), How will that effect the vtables?

Comment: You'd potentially face the same issue with diamond inheritance, with or without virtual inheritance.  Take a look at http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html.  Keep in mind that even though that article shows things as "left" and "right", the objects are actually laid out sequentially ("left" is probably laid out first, with "right" following it.).

Comment: What makes multiple inheritance tricky for casting is that some casts point to the middle of the object instead of the top of the object.  In single inheritance, all casts point to the top of the object.  That's true of any kind of multiple inheritance (diamond or not), for the simple fact that layout of one of the parent classes has to come first, and the other has to come second.

Comment: Ahh I see.  Diamond could actually make the problem more complicated, since there will be two BaseInterface twice in the vtables. Casting it first to BaseInteface works because it creates a pointer to the top, then you recast it to the derived interface, which takes the correct pointer. Im going to accept your answer because you explained what was going on, which was my original question.

Answer (score 1):

The code example you posted does not appear to be compilable:

```
DerivedInterface *c = (DerivedInterface *)clientData;
c->DerivedAction(.1);
```

But the definition of the `DerivedInterface` class you posted was:

```
class DerivedInterface
{
public:
    DerivedInterface(){};
    virtual ~DerivedInterface(){};
    virtual DerivedAction()=0;
};
```

The only `DerivedAction`() method your `DerivedInterface` class defines is the one that takes no parameters, while your sample code passes a `float` or a `double` parameter.

This can't even be compiled. If you want to help with figuring out why you are not getting the expected results from your code:

1. Post a minimum, complete example. A minimal code fragment that will build and compile, but demonstrates your problem.
2. Explain what results you expect, and what results you get with the sample code.

Posting random snippets of code, that won't even compile, but asking questions that presume the code compiles and runs, as is here, isn't likely to result in helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting `Derived*` to `void*`, and then trying to cast that `void*` to `DerivedInterface*`, you cannot perform casts like this with multiple inheritance (or reliably with any inheritance), `DerivedInterface` does not reside at the same address as `Derived`. The only thing you can do with a `void*` is cast it back to the original object.

Either of the following will work:

```
Derived<short>* a = new Derived<short>;
DerivedInterface *c = a;
c->DerivedAction(.01);
```

---

```
Derived<short>* a = new Derived<short>;
BaseInterFace *cd = a;
DerivedInterface *c = dynamic_cast<DerivedInterface*>(cd);
c->DerivedAction(.01);
```

---

I you must use a `void*` you will have to cast it back to `Derived<short>` first. Please consider avoiding c-style casts, the compiler is able to pick up certain kinds of invalid casts if you use the c++ ones.

Comment: I need to cast from void*.  I've tried casting first to BaseInterFace then using dynamic casting to DerivedInterface. `BaseInterFace *b2 = (BaseInterFace *)cd;
 printf("InputClass: %s\n",b2->GetNameOfClass());
 DerivedInterface *c = dynamic_cast<DerivedInterface*>(b2);`  This seems to work. Im going to test it a bit. Thanks for your tip in updating my question as well.

Comment: @jmerkow There's no guarantee that will work, it's still undefined behavior and will completely break if `BaseInterFace` happens to have any member variables.

Comment: Im using it now.  The real `BaseInterface` has number of has a number of member variables. It seems to be working fine. Is there a better way to interact with template objects without knowing the type that you could point me to?

Comment: Im going to try switching to the decorator pattern.  My gut tells me that MI is going to cause more issues than its worth.

Comment: @jmerkow My bad, it'll work as long as the address of `BaseInterface` happens to be the same as the derived object, but you can't rely on this as it's an implementation detail. Either way maybe you should have a look at your design, multiple inheritance can usually be replaced with other constructs.

Comment: "you cannot perform casts like this with multiple inheritance (or reliably with any inheritance)".  Actually, with single inheritance you can, because all pointers to a single inheritance object point to the same memory location (the top of the full object), regardless of the type of the pointer.  It is only in a multiple inheritance scenario that a cast may give you a different address than you started with, because some casts have to point to somewhere in the middle of the full object.

Comment: @Darryl That is an implementation detail and is technically unreliable, there's no requirement that the vtable is at the top of any given object, although I don't think I've seen it anywhere else in single inheritance on any platform.